# Capybara, OmniAuth and Rolify: Giving a user a role on login

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara, bdd

I am trying to write some integration tests for my app using Capybara. For the app to display correct output, the logged in user must have a specific role. And that's where I get stuck.

Right now, the login mocking looks like this. In `spec_helper.rb` I have:

```
# Trying to configure Capybara to play nice with Omniauth
Capybara.default_host = 'http://example.org'

# Enable omniauth testing mode
OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true

OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:google] = OmniAuth::AuthHash.new({
                                                                :provider => 'google',
                                                                :uid => '1337',
                                                                :info => {
                                                                    'name' => 'JonnieHallman',
                                                                    'email' => 'jon@test.com'
                                                                }
                                                            })
```

Then, in the test itself, to log the user in I just do:

```
  before do
    visit root_path
    click_link "Log In"
  end
```

now, `save_and_open_page` reveals that the user is indeed logged in, but is viewing incorrect output because they don't have a role.

How can I give this mock user a role? When should I do so? (Obviously, before they login -- but I think that that the way it's structured now, the user doesn't exist in the db before the login. Right?)

Any tips would be most welcome.

Comment: That depends on your OmniAuth Callbacks controller. I would expect that you can create a user in the database, and create an authorization with the same provider and uid, add the role to the user and then it would work as you expect in the test.

Comment: But I don't want this to happen with every user -- I need to test different roles. Do I need to create a separate mock callback controller for every user?

Comment: No, you would create a different spec with a different user each time, and test each different flow. I was saying it is dependent on your omniauth controller because how you create and log in users will matter. If you use the standard example's style, then simply creating one before each test as I described above will work.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm being thick about this, but I'm just not clear on where the rolify bit comes in. Do I need to change the omniauth callback controller? I don't want every user to have this role upon creation.

Comment: I'm saying that in your before block create a user with the role you want and an authentication with the same provider and UID that you will be using to authenticate. So you are setting up a situation just for your test, not changing how logging in works.